# Check for password match before form submission with Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm working on a user registration page, where I'm able to validate the forms to make sure it's filled before sending it to the database.
Now what I want to achieve is to make sure, that the user's password matches before the button is being made active to send.

JS:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public http: Http,
              public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              public toastCtrl: ToastController,
              public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

                this.createUsernameForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                  username: ['', Validators.required],
                  password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
                  retypePassword:['',Validators.required]
                });
```

HTML:

```
 <form [formGroup]="createUsernameForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="username"  [(ngModel)]="username" (ngModelChange)="username = $event.toLocaleLowerCase()"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"  [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Retype Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" formControlName="retypePassword"  [(ngModel)]="retypePassword"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div>Passwords do not match!</div>

  <p>
    <button icon-left ion-button large full (click)="createUsername()" [disabled]="!createUsernameForm.valid">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
      Sign In
    </button>
  </p>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom validator, to compare both Controls, and apply this validator in your formGroup.

Example:

```
static EqualValidator(c1: AbstractControl, c2: AbstractControl): ValidatorFn {
        return () => {
            return c1 && c2 && c1.value === c2.value ? null : {notMatch: true};
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `(input)=validatePassword()` on the `<ion-input>` of retype password then do your validation logic inside `validatePassword()` and set the flag to true to enable the button